# R: Using an anonymous function to return the last element of a vector

Tags: r

The task is:

> Now try using evaluate() along with an anonymous function to return
>   the last element of the vector c(8, 4, 0). Your anonymous function
>   should only take one argument which should be a variable x.

My answer is:

```
evaluate(function(x){x[3]},c(8,4,0))
```

with 'evaluate' = function (func, dat)

But the program (swirl, datacamp) is telling me this is incorrect. They're suggesting I use the `length()` function.

How would the `length()` function return the last element in the vector `c(8,4,0)`?

Comment: `evaluate` is not well defined within the context of this question. Maybe you should be asking on some Datacamp forum...? They want you to select the last item -- even when the length is different from 3, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that evaluate is a function that takes a function and some data and applies that function to the data...

```
evaluate <- function(func, dat){
   func(dat)
}
```

then the following should work...

```
evaluate(function(x){x[length(x)]}, dat=c(8,4,0))
```

in this case

```
x[length(x)]
```

will give you the last element of the vector x.

Comment: especially appreciate it since i framed the question really badly. thanks!!!!